# Is it possible to set a cron job or bash script to run X minutes from now?

Tags: bash, cron, expr

I understand I can set a cron job to run every 5 minutes with `crontab -e` by adding a line such as: `*/5 * * * * /path/to/script.sh`.

Is it possible to get the system time in minutes using `date +"%M"` for example, and then set a cron job to run at `date +"%M"` plus 5 minutes?

I know I can get `date +"%M"` + 5 via the following process:

```
$ MIN=`date +"%M"`
$ export MIN
$ expr $MIN + 5
```

Is it possible to use this to set a cron job or script to run at "current time in minutes" plus "X minutes"?

I could imagine this being useful in an application in which a user creates a new document and then is prompted to save or title the document X minutes after creating it.

Comment: What do you mean, cron runs at an exact time. Setting it up to run at current time plus x minutes doesn't even make sense because it would already have to be running to do that...

Comment: In your example you'll have to kill the cronjob after you don't need it anymore. Cron isn't made for this. See "at" below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use the `at` command instead.

With `at`, you can specify the time when a command should be run using time or even keywords like `midnight`, `teatime`, `tomorrow` etc..

You can specify the time after 5 min like this:

```
at now + 5 min
```

And then enter the command you want to schedule. Or you can enter your scheduled jobs in a jobs file and give it as a argument for the `at` command using the `-f` option.

Sample of a jobs file:

```
$ cat myjobs.txt
/path/to/a/shell-script.sh
/path/to/any/command/or/script.sh
```

The following command will execute those jobs after 5 mins:

```
$ at -f myjobs.txt now + 5 min
```

Check this [link](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/06/at-atq-atrm-batch-command-examples/) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the `at` command. Maybe this is what you are looking for.

See

- http://www.computerhope.com/unix/uat.htm
- http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/06/at-atq-atrm-batch-command-examples

Answer (score -3):

Yes you can:

```
*/5 * * * * /path/to/script.sh && crontab -r
```